# mitmproxy how to debug it with pdb (set breakpoint)

Tags: pdb, mitmproxy

Hello I am learning mitmproxy, I have downloaded a binary on Linux , but I have no idea how can I set break point to it using：

```
python3 -m pdb <mitmproxy-py-entry>.py
```

Any idea what is the python file for the .py ?

Comment: What is `mitmproxy-py-entry`?

Comment: I mean the main entry point of the whole mitmproxy/mitmdump (I edited my question a little bit, hope it makes it clear)